# Django: Return values based on condition using SerializerMethodField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-serializer

I have the tables: `User`, `Event` and `EventTicket`. I have to return total transactions and total tickets sold of each event. I am trying to achieve this using Django serializers. Using only serializers, I need to find the following:

```
 1. total tickets sold: count of items in EventTicket table for each event
 2. total transactions: sum of total_amount of items in EventTicket table for each event where payment_status: 1
```

**models.py:**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    first_name              = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False)
    middle_name             = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    last_name               = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)

class Event(models.Model):
    name                    = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    user                    = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='%(class)s_owner', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description             = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
    date_time               = models.DateTimeField()

class EventTicket(models.Model):
    user                    = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event                   = models.ForeignKey(Event,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='event_tickets')
    payment_status          = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0, null=False, blank=False) ## payment_success: 1, payment_failed: 0
    total_amount            = models.FloatField()
    date_time               = models.DateTimeField()
```

My desired output is:

```
"ticket_details": [
      {
        "event_id": 1,
        "event_name": Event-1,
        "total_transactions": 10000, ## Sum of all ticket amounts of event_id: 1, where payment_status: 1
        "total_tickets": 24,  ## Count of all tickets that belong to event_id: 1
      },
      {
        "event_id": 2,
        "event_name": Event-2,
        "total_transactions": 10000, ## Sum of all ticket amounts of event_id: 2, where payment_status: 1
        "total_tickets": 24,  ## Count of all tickets that belong to event_id: 2
      }]
```

This is what I have done:

**serializers.py:**

```
class EventListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

     # ticket_id = serializers.IntegerField(source='id')
     # event_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source='event', read_only=True)
     # event_name = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source='event.name', read_only=True)

     total_transactions = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
     total_tickets = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

     class Meta:
         model = Event
         fields = ('total_transactions', 'total_tickets')

     def get_total_transactions(self, obj):
         return obj.event_tickets.all().aggregate(sum('total_amount'))['total_amount__sum']

     def get_total_tickets(self, obj):
         return obj.event_tickets.all().count()
```

No matter whatever I try, I am always getting this error: `'EventTicket' object has no attribute 'event_tickets'`

Comment: Have you ran manage.py makemigrations and manage.py migrate?

Comment: Yes, I have done all those steps, still I am getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly nice work on your question it is well-written! I don't see anything wrong with your code as it stands out, but the error message does say something that contradicts the code you've posted.

`'EventTicket' object has no attribute 'event_tickets'`

What this is basically saying is that in your `serializer`, although in the `class Meta` you've stated that `model = Event` for some reason the `obj` param in your `serializer method` is of type `EventTicket`, not of type `Event`.

It looks like you've set the correct `related_name` in your `EventTicket` model for the `event` field, nice.

This leads me to believe that your code is correct but the server seems to be running either an old version of the code, or is using a different serializer. Can we confirm that if you put a print statement in, the server actually prints it out in the serializer method?

Answer (score 0):

The error says that `obj` is the instance of `EventTicket`. I guess.. at your view layer, you are calling `EventListSerializer` for `EventTicket` object. You have to call the serializer only for `Event` object.